# Histogram in R from a frequency table with two columns?

Tags: r

I'm working in R and I have a table of session durations in seconds, and the count of users with a session of that length. Here are some sample rows:

```
sessionDuration,users
936,5
937,3
938,2
939,4
940,12
941,2
942,4
943,1
944,3
945,4
...
```

I'd like to draw a histogram showing the distribution of the session durations. For example, columns with labels for 200-400,400-600,600-800,800-1000 seconds, and then the count of users as the y-value of each column.

How can I do this?

This is as far as I've got:

```
mydata <- read.csv('./session-durations.csv', header=TRUE)
hist(mydata$users,main="Distribution of users",xlab="users")
```

But this shows me the distribution of the value of "users" only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(sampledata$users), 
       function(x)rep(sampledata[x,1], sampledata[x,2])))
hist(a, main="Distribution of users",xlab="users")
```